# Android different multiple color in textview based on background

Tags: java, android, android-layout, colors, textview

I am trying to change the text color in a textview like this.

[image: TextView]

When the background is blue, the text is white. And the text is blue when the background is white.

How can I do this in Android?

Comment: You can get this effect by setting the text color to blue then using xor when you draw the text over the background.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for direction. I'm able to do it now. I referred to this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943091/invert-paint-color-based-on-background